# UIView's drawRect is not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to display horizontal and/or vertical lines in a grid. So I created a `UIView` subclass `GridLines` that draws lines in `drawRect:`. I then create two of these (one vertical, one not), and add them as subviews to my primary view (`Canvas`) also `UIView` derived. The other custom subviews I add to `Canvas` are displayed, removed, etc. properly, but the `GridLines` objects are not, and their `drawRect:`s never get called. When I had this line-drawing code in `[Canvas drawRect:]` (which is now disabled), it displayed the grid properly.

Looking through similar questions, it seems most people with this issue are calling `drawRect` in a non-`UIView` derived class, but mine is a `UIView`.

Am I missing something here?

GridLines.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface GridLines : UIView
{
  BOOL mVertical;
}
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) _frame vertical: (BOOL) _vertical;
@end
```

GridLines.m:

```
#import "GridLines.h"
@implementation GridLines
- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) _frame vertical: (BOOL) _vertical
{
  if ((self = [super initWithFrame: _frame]))
  {
    mVertical = _vertical;
  }

  return self;
}

- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) _rect
{
  NSLog(@"[GridLines drawRect]");
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [[UIColor clearColor] set];
  UIRectFill([self bounds]);

  if (mVertical)
  {
    for (int i = 50; i < self.frame.size.width; i += 50)
    {
      CGContextBeginPath(context);
      CGContextMoveToPoint(context, (CGFloat)i, 0.0);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, (CGFloat)i, self.frame.size.height);
      [[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
      CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    for (int j = 50; j < self.frame.size.height; j += 50)
    {
      CGContextBeginPath(context);
      CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, (CGFloat)j);
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width, (CGFloat)j);
      [[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];
      CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
      CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    }
  }
}
@end
```

In another UIView derived class:

```
- (void) createGrids
{
  mHorizontalLines = [[GridLines alloc] initWithFrame: self.frame vertical: NO];
  mVerticalLines   = [[GridLines alloc] initWithFrame: self.frame vertical: YES];
  [self addSubview: mHorizontalLines];
  [self addSubview: mVerticalLines];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a `frame v bounds` problem.

```
mHorizontalLines = [[GridLines alloc] initWithFrame: self.frame vertical: NO];
mVerticalLines   = [[GridLines alloc] initWithFrame: self.frame vertical: YES];
```

`frame` is kept in superview's co-ordinate space, if `self.frame` is offset more that it is wide, when you set these new views to that frame, they'll be clipped to rect of `self`.

try changing this to `self.bounds`, which should have origin = {0,0}